# pdf 1.8.1 Flutter - Unable to display the document

Tags: flutter, pdf, dart

I was trying to use PDF library for Flutter using the package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf)

the idea is to create something like [this](https://davbfr.github.io/dart_pdf/):  which is the example in the package's page.

---

the problem is that if I run the Demo example there, it works exactly as the example, which is fine.

- [demo example](https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/tree/master/demo)

But if I create a new project and COPY/PASTE all *.dart files and pubspec.yaml : it doesn't work. The script creates the file, I can downloading it or print it as well, but doesn't show the file.

I'm not using project with more information, I'm just copying the same code to a clean project and I'm also getting packages in pubspec.yaml

did someone has the same problem? I will post an image below.

in addition: I'M RUNNING BOTH PROJECTS AS FLUTTER WEB, IN CHROME

thank you for your help!! :)

[image]

below a 'hello world' code that showed me the same error..

```
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final pw.Document doc = pw.Document();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<Uint8List> generateDocument(PdfPageFormat format) async {
      doc.addPage(pw.Page(
          pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.standard,
          build: (pw.Context context) {
            return pw.Center(
              child: pw.Text("Hello World"),
            ); // Center
          })); // Page
      return doc.save();
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: PdfPreview(
          maxPageWidth: 700,
          build: generateDocument,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you add the javascript code? 
you should add the code in the index.html.

for example) 
like this,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="Rakuraku Flutter.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="rakuraku">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>

  <title>rakuraku</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
</head>
<body id="flutter">
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.4.456/pdf.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.4.456/pdf.worker.min.js";
  </script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: REALLY THANK YOU!  How did you know that? I already checked all the documentation and it doesn't say anything about the extra code in index.html haha.

Comment: I see that I was missing: <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.4.456/pdf.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.4.456/pdf.worker.min.js";
  </script> Do you know if I can use this code for a Comercial use?